# C - fdopen gives a stream for STDOUT_FILENO that doesn't work with fflush

Tags: c, posix

When I run the following C code on a Linux system:

```
printf("This is sentence 1. ");
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "This is sentence 2.\n", 20);
```

I get the output in a wrong order:

```
This is sentence 2.
This is sentence 1.
```

I understand that this happens because 'printf' sends the data to a buffer in the user space, and it takes some time to get to the kernel space, while 'write' sends the data immediately to the cache buffer in the kernel space.

A way to fix this is by flushing the data from user-space buffer to kernel-space buffer this way:

```
printf("This is sentence 1. ");
fflush(stdout);
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "This is sentence 2.\n", 20);
```

And then the correct output is received:

```
This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2.
```

Another way that I tried to solve this issue is by trying to get the stdout stream from the STDOUT_FILENO fd:

```
FILE *file = fdopen(STDOUT_FILENO, "w");
printf("This is sentence 1. ");
fflush(file);
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "This is sentence 2.\n", 20);
```

But, I get the output in the wrong order:

```
This is sentence 2.
This is sentence 1.
```

In order to make sure that STDOUT_FILENO is a fd that represents stdout, I converted stdout to a fd:

```
int fd = fileno(stdout);
if(fd == STDOUT_FILENO)
    printf("fd == STDOUT_FILENO == %d\n", fd);
```

And received the expected output:

```
fd == STDOUT_FILENO == 1
```

So, the question is why when converting STDOUT_FILENO to a stream that should be equivalent to stdout, the 'fflush' function doesn't work? Is there a problem with the way I use 'fdopen'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The buffer is a property of the stdio stream, that is, the `FILE` structure.  `printf` is always printing to `stdout`, so it's the `stdout` stream you need to call `fflush` on.  When you wrote

```
FILE *file = fdopen(STDOUT_FILENO, "w");`
```

, that gave you a *second*, completely independent `FILE` stream, with its own buffer.  But you don't print anything to that stream, so falling `fflush` on it accomplishes nothing, and meanwhile, the text you printfed to `stdout` remains unflushed.

If you've got buffered output on `stdout`, it's `stdout` you must call `fflush` on.  (Or, alternatively, add a `\n` at the end of the string you print with `printf`, since `stdout` is typically line-buffered, at least if it's going to a terminal.)

Answer (score 0):

In this:

```
FILE *file = fdopen(STDOUT_FILENO, "w");
printf("This is sentence 1. ");
fflush(file);
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "This is sentence 2.\n", 20);
```

`printf` does not send anything to `file`. It writes to `stdout`.

Each `FILE` object contains its own buffer (whether directly or via pointer to allocated memory). When you execute `printf("This is sentence 1. ");`, it writes to the buffer in the `stdout` `FILE`. When you `fflush(file);`, it flushes the buffer in `file`.

To make this work, you could write `fprintf(file, "This is sentence 1. ");`, since that will write to the buffer in `file`, and `fflush(file);` will flush it.